# The requested address is not valid in its context generates an error when trying send xml to server using sockets in C#

Tags: c#, xml, sockets

I'm trying to send xml over server using sockets in C3 .net shows below error:

The requested address is not valid in its context

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details:

```
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: The requested address is not valid in its context

    Source Error: 


    Line 38: 
    Line 39: 
    Line 40:             sock.Bind(ipEnd);
    Line 41:             sock.Listen(100);
    Line 42:
```

Code behind:

```
IPEndPoint ipEnd = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("172.16.0.32"),50001);/*the ip of the server*/
           Socket sock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

        sock.Bind(ipEnd);
        sock.Listen(100);

        Socket clientsock = sock.Accept();

        byte[] b = new byte[1024 * 10000];

        int recsize = clientsock.Receive(b);

        FileStream fileStream = new FileStream("PersonData.xml", FileMode.Create);
        fileStream.Write(b, 0, recsize);
        fileStream.Close();
```